# How to redirect an url address to my address

Tags: url, redirect, dns, web

I have a website that I should puts it online in 48 hours ,but I didn't get my domaine name until now and I should put my website address in a brochure tomorrow.

Our company has a website ,so my boss asked me to put my website under the company website till I'll have my domainename,but the problem is that we are gone publish our address in a brochure.

**my question is:**

whenI put my website under the companysite it will have the address:

www.companyName.com/mysite/Home

then when I will receive my domaine it will be :

www.mysite.com

In the brochure I will put www.companyName.com/mysite/Home so is there any way to put that address on the brochure and then that address will redirect to my website.

I mean when the user put www.companyName.com/mysite/Home in the adresse bar he will be redirected to www.mysite.com

I hope that I have explained my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the next line of code in your `<header>` of your website which is on the address www.companyName.com/mysite/Home which will then redirect the page to www.mysite.com. The code is:

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://www.yourdomain.com/index.html">
```

Change the URL to the url of the website you want to redirect to. content is a number of seconds a visitor will wait untill the redirect happens

Answer (score 0):

You have the server respond with a `301 Moved Permanently` status and a `Location: http://example.com/` header with the new URL.

The specifics of how you do that will depend on the server. With Apache you would normally use a [`Redirect` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect).

Since you are redirecting *from* only certain local paths (and not the entire domain), you have to do this at the HTTP level not the DNS level.